# Adding button next to every node in ASP.NET TreeView

Tags: asp.net, treeview, asp.net-1.1

I am building an interface which requires two server side button next to every tree node in ASP.NET 1.1.

[image]

Please let me know, how to integrate two server side button inside asp.net tree-view control.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `TreeView` does not exist in 1.1. [It was introduced in 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: I am using IE Web Controls

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you provide an MSDN link?

Comment: [link for your reference](http://forums.asp.net/p/134991/134991.aspx/1?Welcome+to+the+Internet+Explorer+Web+Controls)

Comment: This looks like the relevant [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms529254.aspx). Have you considered upgrading to the current version of ASP.NET and using the built in [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx) control?